# Indexing on local table in SQLServer2008

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2012, clustered-index, database-tuning

SQL Server help:

I have created a local table @Emp in my database and inserted values to it. Can I add clustered indexes on this table? I need to reduce my sorting cost (78%), hence I need to do this.

Comment: Yes, you can... CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idxName
    ON dbo.TestTable (TestCol1);

Comment: @User2012384 No, user is using a table variable -- only primary keys and unique constraints are allowed in definition.

Comment: During creation of table variable we can. Not after that. `declare @table1 table(a int primary key clustered)`